# Java 8 Streams - Nested Maps to List

Tags: java, list, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

```
firstlist
  .stream()
  .map( x -> { 
            return secondList
               .stream()
               .map( y -> { //return a string } )
               .collect(Collectors.toList()) // "Output" I need
              }
       )
    .//Get the "Output" here
```

I have two list. the item in first list have to compared with second list and new list have to built.

**Sample Input**

```
List 1 : [ { "id" ; 3, "names" : ["test","test2"] }]
List 2 : [ {"name": :"test" , "age" :3}]
```

**Output:**

```
List 3 : [ {"id" : 3, "name" : "test", "age" :3} ]
```

P.S: The `names` in first list should be checked against second list

Comment: can you show us some input output, your question is unclear

Comment: on what criteria are you merging?

Comment: Edited my question with sample input and output.

Comment: @madhairsilence could you pls share the `POJO` for both the lists ?

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik I have given the sample list

Comment: @madhairsilence is the class in List 3 different than those from List 1 and List 2? Please post those example classes as *code*

Comment: Does not matter. Can be a new class or a hashmap. The key here is nested stream. Second one depends on first.

Comment: @madhairsilence http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive -> you mostly ignore all the comments asking for clarification on the question and answers. If you want a usable solution you should learn to work with us, and provide us the information we need

Comment: @Lino You should see the page fully. I have replied to all comments. I replied to your comments and you replied to mine after 2 hours. See who is irresponsive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need something like this :

```
List<ObjectA> firstlist = new ArrayList<>();
firstlist.add(new ObjectA(3, Arrays.asList("test", "test2")));
List<ObjectB> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
secondList.add(new ObjectB("test", 3));

List<ObjectC> result = firstlist.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> secondList.stream()
                .filter(b -> a.getNames().contains(b.getName()))
                .map(c -> new ObjectC(a.getId(), c.getName(), c.getAge()))
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If I understand your question you have three Object different like this:

```
@Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class ObjectA {
    private int id;
    private List<String> names;
}

@Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class ObjectB {
    private String name;
    private int age;
}

//And the result Object you want to get
@Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class ObjectC {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

---

The outputs of this example is :

```
[ObjectC(id=3, name=test, age=3)]
```

---

<sub>For the annotation I'm using Lombok for that</sub>

Comment: Somehow I get java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to ObjectC

Comment: @madhairsilence can you please show us how you fill your Lists? from the question I assumed that you use Objects not maps, so please edit your question and provide to us how you fill this lists, and about the error it is logic It seems you mix between my data type and your data type for that you get this error, I'm waiting for your edit.

Comment: OK. one small mistake. The actual error is  I get java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to "ObjectA". And I face the exception exactly at "collect". If I remove that, the code works fine

Comment: Hi @madhairsilence listen carefully, can you please show us your code? I can't answer without seeing your code!

Answer (score 0):

is it what you are looking for?

```
        firstList
            .stream()
            .filter(item -> secondList
                .stream().anyMatch(item::matches))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Looks close. But its not actual match. is the attribute from first list should match an attribute from second list

Answer (score 0):

Your **attributes** are so general, I think you'd better introduce some *custom class* to replace the `map` and to meet your requirements, here is a simple demo for the *input* and *output* in your question as:

```
public class SimpleFlatMap {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<EntityWithNames> listOne = new ArrayList<>();
        listOne.add(new EntityWithNames());
        List<EntityWithAge> listTwo = new ArrayList<>();
        listTwo.add(new EntityWithAge("test", 3));
        List<EntityWithNameAndAge> listThree = listOne.stream().map(withNames -> {
            EntityWithAge entityWithAge = listTwo.stream()
                    .filter(withAge -> withNames.names.contains(withAge.name))
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(new EntityWithAge());
            return new EntityWithNameAndAge(withNames.id, entityWithAge.name, entityWithAge.age);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(listThree);
    }

    static class EntityWithNames {
        Long id;
        List<String> names;

        public EntityWithNames() {
            id = 3L;
            names = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("test", "test1"));
        }
    }

    static class EntityWithAge {
        String name;
        int age;

        public EntityWithAge() {
            name = "default";
            age = -1;
        }

        public EntityWithAge(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
    }

    static class EntityWithNameAndAge {
        Long id;
        String name;
        int age;

        public EntityWithNameAndAge(Long id, String name, int age) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("id: %d, name: %s, age: %d", id, name, age);
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
[id: 3, name: test, age: 3]
```

Comment: Would have preferred a sleeker version.

Answer (score 0):

You might want the following:

```
List<ClassWithId>  list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<ClassWithAge> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

list1.add(new ClassWithId(3, Arrays.asList("test", "test2")));
list2.add(new ClassWithAge("test", 4));

List<ClassResult> list3 = list2.stream()
                               .map(i -> new ClassResult(
                                               list1.stream()
                                                    .filter(j -> j.getList().contains(i.getName()))
                                                    .map(j -> j.getId())
                                                    .findFirst().get(), 
                                               i.getName(), i.getAge()))
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This solution assumes the structure of the following two input objects and the output object:

- ClassWithId

  ```
  private int id;
  private List<String> list;
  ```
- ClassWithAge

  ```
  private String name;
  private int age;
  ```
- ClassResult

  ```
  private int id;
  private int age;
  private String name;
  ```